# How to select or highlight text in java script on mousemove

Tags: javascript

How to select or highlight text in java script on mousemove. can anybody provide example.if user touches the screen.I want to highlight or select particular word

Thanks

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to do that with javascript when this can be done with pure css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the jQuery MouseMove event handler, documented here:
http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Then highlight the background of the text with the jQuery .css property, documented here:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Hope this helps!

Comment: if user touch particular word that word only highlight can you tell  how to do